Python Split and assign into new Columns
I have been worked in a dataframe with one column which has data for different calls to APIs.
I need to split by "," and add new columns depends of the method's name (each API contains different input names).
For example:



Column A
Column B




callToAPI1(), Peter, 1979-07-01, male
callToAPI1()


callToAPI2(), Roxana, 1980-01-01, female, Doctor, University of Toronto
callToAPI2()


callToAPI1(), Adrian, 1998-03-15, male
callToAPI1()



I used the next instruction:
df.loc[df['Column B'] == 'callToAPI1()', ['Name','Date','Sex']] = df['Column A'].str.split(', ',expand=False)[1]
It works but the instruction copy the same content of first row (new columns) into the next match, like this:



Column A
Column B
Name
Date
Sex
Occupation
University




callToAPI1(), Peter, 1979-07-01, male
callToAPI1()
Peter
1979-07-01
male
null
null


callToAPI1(), Adrian, 1998-03-15, male
callToAPI1()
Peter
1979-07-01
male
null
null



How can I resolve this issue?
Thanks!

You can create a mask (df['Column B'] == 'callToAPI1()') and use df.loc:
import pandas as pd


def _run(df):
    df[['Method', 'Name', 'Date', 'Sex', 'Occupation', 'University']] = df['Column A'].str.split(',\\s*', expand=True)
    mask = df['Column B'] == 'callToAPI1()'
    df.loc[mask, ['Name', 'Date', 'Sex', 'Occupation', 'University']] = df.loc[mask,
                                                                               ['Name', 'Date', 'Sex', 'Occupation', 'University']].ffill()

    df.drop(columns=['Column A', 'Column B'], inplace=True)
    return df


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column A': ['callToAPI1(), Peter, 1979-07-01, male', 'callToAPI2(), Roxana, 1980-01-01, female, Doctor, University of Toronto', 'callToAPI1(), Adrian, 1998-03-15, male'],
    'Column B': ['callToAPI1()', 'callToAPI2()', 'callToAPI1()']
})

print(_run(df))



Prints
         Method    Name        Date     Sex Occupation             University
0  callToAPI1()   Peter  1979-07-01    male       None                   None
1  callToAPI2()  Roxana  1980-01-01  female     Doctor  University of Toronto
2  callToAPI1()  Adrian  1998-03-15    male       None                   None

